# ReactJS - Checkbox onChange event not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding, checkboxlist, react-dom

I'm trying to implement a fields set of checkboxes in React rendered from an object as follows:

```
constructor() {

    this.state.todo = {
        eat: true,
        sleep: false,
        react: true
    }

    this.toggleCheckbox = this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this);
}

toggleCheckbox(e){

    console.log(e); // nothing :-/
}

render() {

    return (
    <div>
    { Object.keys(this.state.todo).map((val, i) => (          
        <div key={i} >
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                value={val} 
                onChange={this.toggleCheckbox} 
                checked={this.state.todo[val]} 
                /><label>{val}</label>
        </div>
     ))}
     </div>
    )
}
```

Everything renders correctly but I am not able change any of the checkboxes. console logging the `toggleCheck()` event is not being triggered.

Ive tried using `onClick` vs `onChange` which has no effect.

Comment: actually the problem as in CSS, not JS. these checkboxes are custom styled using <label>'s and the hiding/placement of the label was blocking the event. apologies again about the false alarm

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the keys from `this.state.tables`, but your state is called `this.state.todo`.

You can use each value as `name` instead and toggle the relevant `todo` state property with that.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todo: {
      eat: true,
      sleep: false,
      react: true
    }
  };

  toggleCheckbox = e => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todo: {
        ...prevState.todo,
        [name]: !prevState.todo[name]
      }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(this.state.todo).map((val, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={val}
              onChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
              checked={this.state.todo[val]}
            />
            <label>{val}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I was just about to ask about `this.state.tables`, as I was trying it out 

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. `this.state.tables` in my actual code - `todo` was for this example but I forgot to change that line

Comment: @yevg Ah, I see. That's alright. Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new), or did the answer maybe work for you?